# In jQuery, can I use slideDown() as a scroll down feature for a div with large content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want is use an effect that is much smoother to scroll down and up, than the function I have.

I have an outer div (with overflow:hidden) and a div smaller in width ( class='all_content').

```
<a href='#' class='up'>Up</a> 
<a href='#' class='down'>Down</a>
<div class='container'>
<div class='all_content'> All the content is here </div>
</div>
```

I have that code:

```
$(".down").click(function () {
        $(".all_content").animate({marginTop: '-=20px'}, 0);
    });

$(".up").click(function () {
        $(".all_content").animate({ marginTop: '+=20px' }, 0);
    });
```

But it feels really sloppy with that +20px margin.

Can I use slideDown()? Should I use the scrollTop with it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't really get the question, but maybe it'll be helpful if you post some HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to the [`scrollTo()` plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html), which you can call like this:

```
$(".all_content").scrollTo({top: "+20px"}, 1000);
```

Edit: Here's a revised version of the code you posted:

```
$(".down").click(function() {
    $(".all_content").scrollTo({
        top: '-=20px'
    }, 1000);
});

$(".up").click(function() {
    $(".all_content").scrollTo({
        top: '+=20px'
    }, 1000);
});​
```

Make sure you include the `scrollTo` plugin before you include your main js file(s).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried to call this function, after having included the plugin. But the function has not been called. Is this exactly the way it should be called? Thanks again

Comment: It's just an example. Let me revise the code you posted to work with `scrollTo`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be a problem, If you define your div with overflow:scroll like this:

```
div 
{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The problem is that the scrollbar that appears looks different from one browser to another. What I want is use those "Up" and "down" links, along with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery scrollTop() method:

```
$(".all_content").scrollTop(20);
```